# discord py - leaderboard picks wrong user

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, discord.py

I have a question, that destroys my brain for hours now. I want to check if a message author and a specific user on my server have the same id. If yes, then another action run.

So, that's work. But I get the user from the 2nd place in my leaderboard and i.. just don't know why, I would like a fix for that.

Json-File Structure:

```
{"327176944640720906": {"level": 29, "xp": 165, "secXP": 4508, "cooldown": 1611183963.9734623}, {..}, {..}}
```

My code:

```
with open("level.json", "r") as a:
         level = json.load(a)
         high_score_list = sorted(level, key=lambda x: level[x].get('secXP'), reverse=True)
         count1 = 0
         user = None
         for number, user in enumerate(high_score_list):
             if count1 == 1:
                break
         count1 += 1
         # Wrong ID (second place) at "User2"
         print(f"User2: {user} + msg author: {message.author.id} - {message.author.name}")
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your `level.json` to get a better idea of what you're doing. Also, just after the `for` loop you have `user = user`; that doesn't do anything, so perhaps there's a typo there? Your `if` statement is also not indented under the `for` loop.

Comment: i updated the topic from me, look above :)

Comment: The sort seems fine as long as you're certain that your `secXP` values are stored as `int` and not `str` (otherwise the sort would lexicographic and not what you'd expect). Aside from that, what is the point of that `for` loop, anyway? You don't use `count1` anywhere else in your code, nor are you incrementing it inside your loop (another indent error, perhaps). Since you have a sorted list, why not just `high_score_list[0]`? That will give you the user ID with the highest `secXP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're certain that your `secXP` values are stored as `int` and not `str`, then your sort is correct (otherwise it would be a lexicographic sort and not what you would expect).

For the sake of completeness, if they *were* `str`s (or you wanted to be absolutely certain), you can easily convert to `int`:

```
key=lambda x: int(level[x].get('secXP'))
```

Since you have a correctly sorted list, the user ID with the greatest `secXP` is simply the first element of the sorted list, e.g.: `high_score_list[0]`.